# No Email in SPUser Object on Site Collection Level?

Tags: email, spuser

I am facing the issue that I do not have a value for email in SPUser object on Site Collection level but in Subsites.

I tried web.EnsureUser as well, which loads the user correctly (-1# issue) but still the Email value and other properties in .User are emtpy.

When trying to send mail to an user using the UI (from users & groups list), I retrieve message "no mail for user" as well.

Since I am running out of ideas I hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User Profile doesn't have email defined for that user. Fill it in in User Profile Service either manually, or by synchronizing it from user account store, such as Active Directory.

Comment: Thanks Jussi. Indeed the Work Email field is not synchronized with AD. I am now wondering which Email SharePoint uses in the SubSite when I go to "Send mail to User". That cant be the Workmail than, any idea?

Comment: It is indeed using the "Work email".